# Recognize multiple scanner bar code

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I have two bar code scanners and I want to know which scanner send the code, because I have two process and each scanner get the code from each process.

I don't know if C# can get the ID from each scanner or the port or something like that.

I'm using C# with windows forms.

---

**Update**

I found this: 
[How do I get serial Port device id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991517/how-do-i-get-serial-port-device-id)

and this:
[Get List of connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices)

I was thinking know the scanner with the serial port... maybe is not the best way but will work

Comment: Can you be more specific. Are you using a web application or windows application? Because if you are trying to read on a browser it will be difficult to get the client ports.

Comment: If the scanners are USB and conform to the HID (Human Interface Device) interface, then this answer, and especially the link to the CodeProject article, might be of some use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517698/how-to-detect-nonpresent-devices-using-c-sharp/27519823#27519823

Comment: Thanks, I put in the description: I'm using C# with windows forms. "Desktop app"

Comment: What are the brands and models of the scanners please.

Comment: @RenniePet but this only know the port or something like ID of the scanner?

Comment: @dan-gph just a inalambric scanner, it's a generic scanners :(

Comment: It's been years and years since I worked with that code, but it looks like it can find a "product ID" and a "vendor ID" for the attached device. Take a look at the CodeProject article.

Comment: @LuisMedellín, you will have to be more specific than that. With some scanners you can program them to add a prefix or suffix to the barcode that you get. I know you can do this with Datalogic scanners anyway.

Comment: @dan-gph It's all that I have, but sounds good program the scanners, let me see if I can program the scanners that I have

Comment: @LuisMedellín, you will have to look up the manual.